# What does a good injector spray pattern look like for a four hole injector?

Tags: fuel-injectors, mazda-626

I have four hole injectors like this on my 98 Mazda 626 2L GF:

[image]

What does the proper spray pattern for this type of injector look like?

Answer (score 7):

Basically, the spray pattern should be conical and even, without streaming, dripping, or uneven spray occurring. This ensures the fuel is atomizing as much as possible. Here is a granular image which shows what a multi-port injector (like yours) should look like:

[image]

You should be looking at 3rd from the left.

From your image on the [other question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/40317/4152), I'm not necessarily seeing any suspect spray patterns. After you clean the injectors, any deviance in the spray patterns should be cleaned up.